# Averaging several factor of multiplication function

Tags: average

So, I have these kind of equations:

$k_{A_1}*k_{B_1}*k_{C_1} = f_1$

$k_{A_2}*k_{B_2}*k_{C_2} = f_2$

...

$k_{A_7}*k_{B_7}*k_{C_7} = f_7$

What I have is $f_1$,$f_2$,...$f_7$
Is there any way to get the average value of $k_A$,$k_B$, and $k_C$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you would be able to deduce the average value of kA, kB, and kC here.

Maybe there's an implicite relation to kX families ?

Comment: Yeah, I think this can not be solved. I should define the problem differently.